# Join two Arrays for MatTableDataSource - Angular/TS

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have two Objects

```
Client = [id, name]
Order = [id, clientId]
```

I have an Array of Orders and want to Display them in an mat-table. I got everything up and run (so display ID and ClientID) but how can I combine my ClientID from the Order in the with my Client so I can display the real name?

I could not find anything. Might not Googled the right thing and could not come up with an Idea for that simple Task!

Best Regards!

Comment: Hello Marvin, and welcome to SO! Your question is not directly related to Angular. What you're looking for is JavaScript Array manipulation techniques. I strongly recommend looking into `.map` and `.find` [methods of the Array Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

You could just group your orders by clientId and then add the resulting orders-array per client to the client object:

```
const clients = [
  { id: 1, name: "first" },
  { id: 2, name: "second" }
];

const orders = [
  { id: 1, clientId: 1, text: "First Order" },
  { id: 2, clientId: 2, text: "Second Order" },
  { id: 3, clientId: 1, text: "Third Order" }
];

const groupedOrders = {};
orders.forEach(order => {
  if (!groupedOrders[order.clientId]) {
    groupedOrders[order.clientId] = [];
  }
  groupedOrders[order.clientId].push(order);
});

const groupedClientsAndOrders = clients.map(client => {
  return Object.assign({}, client, { orders: groupedOrders[client.id] || [] });
});
```

This produces a new array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "first",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "clientId": 1,
                "text": "First Order"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "clientId": 1,
                "text": "Third Order"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "clientId": 2,
                "text": "Second Order"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If you need the client per order you can also do the following:

```
const clients = [
  { id: 1, name: "first" },
  { id: 2, name: "second" }
];

const orders = [
  { id: 1, clientId: 1, text: "First Order" },
  { id: 2, clientId: 2, text: "Second Order" },
  { id: 3, clientId: 1, text: "Third Order" }
];

const joinedOrders = orders.map(order => {
  const client = clients.filter(c => c.id == order.id)[0];
  return Object.assign({}, order, { client: client });
});
```